# Cycles and Eevee faceting material in render previews?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

I'm trying to render some materials but when i turn up the metal while the objects have normal information the faces of the objects facet and act as though they have flat normals? I've smooth the objects, re-unwrapped them and even deleted and added new objects. These are just default uv spheres, I have no idea what is causing this.[image: render preview][image: node setup]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Actually this effect can also be made visible when _Metallic_ is set to 0, it is just much more subtle and you have to turn up the strength a lot more (but if you set the strength very low, it goes away even with _Metallic_ at 1). I guess the problem is, since you are assigning new normals to the surface, the smoothing does not work properly anymore. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve with this setup. When I plug a _Bump_ node into the _Normal_ input of the _Principled BSDF_ for example, the smoothness is not affected, even at a _Strength_ of 5 or 10.

Comment: I want the surface to be smooth of the ball to be smooth since this is a shader master file i'm slowly starting to build up with some procedural materials. 

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uBMxK9mW-Nvm7R3D9njvYDpDLBVj2qCB/view?usp=sharing) 

@moonboots I've linked the Blend file if you can find something I'm missing?